# Whole program name not visible in nethogs

Tags: command-line, networking

I'm using the command `sudo nethogs` to watch network traffic. I have a problem in that the name of the program is too long (it doesn't fit in the PROGRAM column).

I haven't found any nethogs configuration switch dealing with this issue. Do you know how to see the whole name of the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `nethogs` offers a feature like that, but you can use the process id it shows in the first column to look up the information.

```
cat /proc/$PID/cmdline
```

or

```
ps -p $PID -o 'args='
```

should both work on Linux, for example.